# Is there any good ORM for VistaDB?

Tags: .net, orm, vistadb

I'm looking for a good ORM for VistaDB database. It's for an small desktop application and it might expand in future.

Open source solution will be preferred, but I'm ready to shell out if required.

Regards,

Vikas

Answer (score 3):

Vikas mentioned in a comment Mindscape LightSpeed and the request was made for a link so I'll post that as an answer :-)

Mindscape LightSpeed supports both VistaDB 3.x and 4.x. Has full Visual Studio designer support.

You can find out more about [Mindscape LightSpeed here](http://www.mindscape.co.nz/products/LightSpeed/default.aspx).

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the built in Entity Framework  is ok for most desktop type application (not for nTier for sure).  It is free by being included in .Net 3.5 SP1.  But if you can't handle that requirement for runtime their there are others that support VistaDB as well.

[Entity Spaces](http://www.entityspaces.net/Portal/Default.aspx) has great support and does a LOT more than EF out of the box.

[DevExpress XPO](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/ORM/) has support for VistaDB also (although their 4.x support is just now prepping for release as I write this)

Telerik has also now added their O[pen Access ORM](http://www.telerik.com/products/orm.aspx) with support for VistaDB 4.

We also post [third party tools on a page](http://www.vistadb.net/vistadb/third-party-tools.aspx) within our site (although it is not updated as often as it should be).  Opf is listed on that page as well.

Comment: Thanks, But I went with Mindscape Lighspeed because of it supports LINQ with VistaDB. Setup was a breeze and its too good for the price.

Comment: I have not used Lightspeed.  You should post a link to it for others to find as well.

Comment: Worth noting that DevExpress XPO has LINQ support against VistaDB too.